# Invoking HTML code within discord using JavaScript / VB.Net

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, element, discord

My problem is simple, I'm trying to wright and send text to a person or server using *java-script* or *.Net*. Normally when I do this on sites, you can simply invoke the script and enter text inside. For example, the script bellow will enter text in the youtube search box.

```
Form2.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("search_query").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
```

The script bellow will input text in the discord response box but will immediately disappear. Even when changing the values manually in the html explorer then clicking on the response bar to enter it will cause the text to disappear or revert back to what it was originally.

```
Dim elements2 = Form2.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
For Each element As HtmlElement In elements2
    If element.GetAttribute("className") = "textArea-2Spzkt textArea-2Spzkt scrollbarGhostHairline-1mSOM1 scrollbar-3dvm_9" Then
        element.Focus()
        element.SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    End If
Next
```

**RaW HTML:**

[image]

From looking around, it appears that discord has javascript that can properly invoke the textbox? I'm a little lost on how to approach this to get a working result. If the solution is a javascript I will take that as a respected response too. Any pointers is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I found this javascript to be able to change the text within the response box, but agian, it disappears/reverts once you click on the textbox to send it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("textArea-2Spzkt textArea-2Spzkt scrollbarGhostHairline-1mSOM1 scrollbar-3dvm_9").item("textContent").value="hello"
```

Comment: Based on your screenshot the text area appears to be working with the element's inner text rather than the `value` attribute... What happens if you try `element.InnerText = TextBox1.Text` instead?

Comment: @VisualVincent There is sadly no result at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the code below, and it works：

```
    Dim element1 As HtmlElement
    Dim elements2 = Form2.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
    Dim text1 As String
    Dim text2 As String

    'text1 is the string you want to input with
    text1 = "ok it works again"
    text2 = text1 & "{ENTER}"

    'I find that there is only one element in this collection, so no need to use for each loop
    element1 = elements2.Item(0)
    element1.Focus()

    SendKeys.SendWait(text2)
```

Comment: Is there preferably a non sendkey option? This method is not supper efficient.

Comment: I have found the same result as you while using GetAttribute. And sendkey is my only one solution so far.

Comment: Using your solution I have been able to modify it and get something to work for me. Because of this, I'll give you the solution. If anyone else is trying to do this, you for sure want to add the `SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")` to your project. Without digging through the API and bots of discord, its the only way around it. For a more efficient solution you can add my issued question with just `SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")` in the `for` loop.